# Hall effects in coils

Tags: electromagnetism

If we consider hall effect in moving coil galvanometer then the electric field balances the magnetic field which implies the torque cannot be produced .If that so galvanometer will not work, how is this possible, so why are we not considering hall effect here?

Comment: Why would Hall effect have anything to do with galvanometer function? Hall effect is usually ignored when magnetic force on coil is discussed, as the force depends on current, not on lateral voltage which Hall effect produces.

Comment: but these voltage are produced to balance the magnetic field, and if magnetic force is balanced by electrical force implies no torque at all

Comment: No, Hall voltage is negligible and plays no role in traditional galvanometer. What twists the spring is macroscopic magnetic force acting on the current carrying wire in coil. There is no electric force counter-balancing this force.

Comment: Why is that as wire are normally made of conductors there should be no problem in considering hall effect

Comment: You can consider Hall effect in wire, but when you calculate the voltage, it is minuscule. It has no effect on the function of galvanometer.

Comment: The voltage might be small but the magnetic field will be balanced.

Comment: Yes in the Hall effect the magnetic force on the mobile charge is balanced by electric force on that mobile charge, so net force on the mobile charge has zero component perpendicular to the wire. But this does not make the macroscopic magnetic force on the conductor zero. Those mobile charges push the conductor and that push is what makes it move.

Comment: I m getting a feel that , r u saying that electric force act on positive part but magnetic field do not because it is at rest so net force on conductor by electric field is zero

Comment: You have to distinguish force on mobile charge and force on the conductor. The first is zero, but the second isn't because the conductor experiences net force from the mobile charges that is not balanced by anything (unless the conductor is held in place by some other body such as tape, nails or held in hand). Free, current conducting wire in magnetic field experiences net non-zero force from the mobile charges that form the current.

Comment: Thumbs up ty very much

Comment: Could u answer my moving coil galvanometer question also, thanku in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Hall Effect moves negative charge to one side of a current carrying conductor in a transverse magnetic field and leaves positive charge on the other. The redistribution of charge continues until the side to side electric force equals the magnetic force.  (Measuring the polarity of the side to side voltage does indicate that it is the negative charges which move in a conductor.)  The (negative) current is still flowing down the conductor and being pushed sideways by the magnetic field.  The current repels the negative charge on one side and attracts the positive ions on the other. This electric force moves the conductor sideways.  One might still debate the question:  What's doing the work, the electric or the magnetic field?

Comment: Obviusly we know that magnetic dont do a work ever right